# How do I get the DirectX project templates to appear in Visual Studio?

Tags: directx11, visual-studio

I have DirectX11 on Windows 7, and I also have VS13 Express for Desktop. In some tutorials I have seen that there's an option on VS13 for new project on DirectX, but doesn't appear in my VS13. Is it because I have the for Desktop version instead of the for Windows one? Or do I need to install some DirectX developmentkit first? Thanks.

Comment: This is pretty vague.  Can you link to one of these tutorials so we can see what it says specifically?

Comment: The "DirectX" project templates are for Windows Store Apps / Windows Phone Apps. So I assume it has to do with the version of VS Express you are using (Desktop). However, you don't need anything special as you should just need to create a Win32 Application and include the DX11 headers in your code.

Comment: Thanks man. I ran this basic testing program on Win32 application with DX11 headers and ran perfectly.

Comment: @Inisheer You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 8):

The "DirectX" project templates are for Windows Store Apps / Windows Phone Apps. So I assume it has to do with the version of VS Express you are using (Desktop).

However, you don't need anything special to write traditional desktop apps. You just need to create a Win32 Application and include the DX11 headers in your code

Answer (score 5):

There are no "DirectX" project templates for Win32 desktop applications. You just create a Win32 application and then use Direct3D 11.

If you'd like a Direct3D 11 tutorial for Win32 desktop, I have one on [MSDN Code Gallery](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Direct3D-Tutorial-Win32-829979ef).

**UPDATE** Alternatively, you can install this extension if you move to the VS 2013 Community edition (or VS 2013 Pro+) [Direct3D Win32 Game Visual Studio template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/01/06/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template.aspx) which is also on [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates)